# What is the variable "i" in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I came across a code for prime numbers while going through the practice problems from a book. I am having issues understanding the `i` from the code.

```
def prime_number(num):
  for num in range(num):
    # all prime numbers are greater than 1
    if num > 1:
      for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
          break
      else:
        print(num)
  return
```

Can you please explain to me in detail what the `i` is doing in this code?

Comment: `i in range` does the same thing as `num in range`... Only a different name

Comment: By the way, `num in range(num)` is overriding the parameter, which you shouldn't do

Comment: `i` is the name of a variable ... it could easily be `numberVariable` or `abc123` or any variable name that you can think of

Comment: `i` is just a loop counter variable, it changes from 2, 3, 4, ... up to `num - 1`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer what would be a better way to approach this problem

Comment: Simply don't reuse the parameter name from `def prime_number(num)` as another variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a variable, exactly like `num`.

When using `for` in Python, you write:

```py
for some_variable in some_iterable:
    # code here
```

This will loop over the iterable, each time assigning the next value to the variable.

Calling `range(x, y, z)` creates an iterable that starts at `x`, ends at `y`, at steps `z` amount each time. So if you wrote:

```py
for i in range(5, 25, 5):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

You'd get the output: `5 10 15 20` .

The loop in your function loops for every value from 2 to `num - 1`, incrementing up by one each time, and setting `i` equal to the value.

Answer (score 1):

It gets the values of the elements of an iterable object.

From [OneCricketeer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462706/what-is-the-variable-i-in-a-for-loop#comment115735681_65462706):

> i in range does the same thing as num in range... Only a different name

`i` is a temporary variable used to store the integer value of the current position in the `range` of the `for` loop that only has scope within its `for` loop. You could use any other variable name in place of `i` such as `num` or `x` or `j`.

The loop in your function loops for every value from 2 to `num`, incrementing up by one each time, and setting `i` equal to the value.

You can improve your code like this:

```
def prime_number(number):
  for num in range(number):
   # all prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
  return
```